# Fetch data from 2 tables, when either not present in 2nd table or has a null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, left-join

I am trying to fetch data from 2 tables - table_a and table_b.
Columns of table_a - a1,a2,a3
Columns of table_b - b1, b2, b3

Now the foreign key mapping is a1 and b2.

All values in table_a may not be present in table_b. And the values in table_b, may have the value in column b3 as null at times.

I am trying to fetch all the data that is either present in table_a and not in table_b and the values that are present in both the tables, but the value of the columnn b3 is null in table_b
Could you please help me with a SQL query for the same?

I am currently using the below -

```
select * 
from table_a left join 
     table_b 
     on (a1 = b2 and (b3 is null or b1 is null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to fetch all the data that is either present in table_a and not in table_b and the values that are present in both the tables, but the value of the columnn b3 is null in table_b

Consider:

```
select * 
from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.b2 = a.a1
where b.b3 is null
```

Rationale: the `left join` along with `were` condition `b.b3 is null` covers the following situations

- there is no match in `table_b` (then `b.b3` ends up `null`)
- there is a match in `table_b` but `b3` is `null` in the matching record
- if there is a match

Comment: You could also use a `RIGHT JOIN`.  Basically, "everything from the table on the `LEFT` (or `RIGHT`) will be included, along with any matching columns from the "other" side."

Comment: @MikeRobinson . . . For anyone who reads from left-to-right, `left join` is generally much simpler to follow:  "Keep everything in the table name you just read and *then* matching columns in the subsequent tables."  There are very few occasions where I find `right join` to be preferable.